# VGA Controller is Intel's but graphic card is AMD/ATI, and 3d acceleration is not supported

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I typed `lspci -nn` in the Terminal.
And this is what it says :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port [8086:0151] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:1e16] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e59] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e03] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8750M] [1002:6600]
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

As you can see, VGA controller is Intel's but Display controller is AMD/ATI's,

and I have 'RADEON GRAPHICS - AMD' sticker on my laptop.

However, [This document](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) says like I should only check VGA compatible controller, not Display controller.

Another problem is that my 3d acceleration is not working.

When I type `fglrxinfo` or `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`, it says

```
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  136 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

This also occurs when I try to play 3D games, of course.

However, as you can see, my graphic card is one of Radeon HD 8xxx series (a.k.a. OLAND).

I think that's why the Ubuntu drivers didn't work.

Is there any unofficial drivers to make my 3D acceleration work?

Comment: The Intel VGA adapter is the GPU part of your processor. Usually you should be fine with the AMD drivers. Did you already try to run "sudo aticonfig --inital" to get an automatically configured xorg.conf yet? Be warned, this might break your xorg.conf settings, so if you have an xorg.conf, make a backup, and have a live cd ready to copy it back, just in case.

Comment: @soulsource What is the difference between 'VGA compatible controller' and 'Display controller'? I'm sure ATI Radeon is my graphic card. This is a laptop.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but would guess that they mean the same.

Comment: @soulsource I wonder why their values are different?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Both are listed, because, both are connected to the PCI(E) bus, and of course they have different PCI addresses. Why one is labeled VGA- and the other display-controller I can't say. When I get home in 2 hours, I'll check on my PC, which has two AMD graphics cards (onboard and discrete) how they are labeled.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use those two Open Source drivers:

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
- https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

**Attention**!! → If you already installed the official ATI driver so you need to remove all it's files, look at this documentation:

- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx
- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Hybrid_Graphics_and_Catalyst

Comment: It's strange.. amdconfig says no supported adapters but my computer has a label named "RADEON GRAPHICS - AMD"... and Display controller is AMD/ATI's. Is my system broken, or it is Ubuntu's bug?

On my VirtualBox on Windows 8, the Ubuntu didn't work correctly before I installed fglrx... I am so confused.